# Can we change the traversal identifier in HTML page from a dotted rectangle to a block?

Tags: javascript, html

When we traverse in an HTML page by pressing the tab key , a dotted rectangle appears , by which we can identify the position/element in the page. My question is can i make it a block i.e the selected elements(links , tabs) color and background will change at the time of traverse ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the browser's default style as described in [this MDC article](http://www.mozilla.org/access/keyboard/snav/css_usage.html).

Basic example:

```
:focus {
    background-color: #aaa;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/otoco5

The `:focus` selector works in every browser you could expect, except IE 6 and 7.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3afocus),[2](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/focus.html)</sup>

Comment: Nice - I never knew about that.

Comment: Perfect ! I've to do it only for IE8, let see it works or not.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a CSS rule using the [`:focus`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes) pseudo-class:

> The :focus pseudo-class applies while an element has the focus (accepts keyboard events or other forms of text input).